# About network flow equilibrium property

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am reading about network flow algorithms in Robert Sedwicks book on Graph algorithms. Following is text snippet from the book.

> Property: Any st-flow has the property that outflow from s is equal to
>   the inflow to t.
>
> Proof: Augument the network with an edge from a dummy vertex into s,
>   with flow and capacity equal to the outflow from "s", and with an edge
>   from "t" to another dummy vertex, with flow and capactiy equal to the
>   inflow to "t". Then, we can prove a more general property by
>   induction: Inflow is equal to outflow for any set of vertices  (not
>   including the dummy vertices).
>
> This property is true for any single vertex, by local equilibrium.
>   Now, assume that it is true for a given set of vertices "S"  and that
>   we add a single vertex "v" to make the set S1 = S U {v}. To compute
>   inflow and outflow for S1, note that each edge from "v" to some vertex
>   in S reduces outflow  (from V) by the same amount as it reduces inflow
>   (to S); each edge to v from some vertex in S reduces inflow (to v) by
>   the same amount as it reduces outflow (from S); and all other edges
>   provide inflow or outflow for S1 if and only if they do so for S or v.
>   Thus, inflow and outflow are equal for S1, and the value of the flow
>   is equal to the sum of the values of the flows of v and S minus sum of
>   the flows on the edges connectin v to a vertex in S (either
>   direction).
>
> Applying this property to the set of all the networks vertices, we
>   find that the source's inflow from its associated dummy vertex is
>   equal to the sink's outflow to tits assicated dummy vertex.

My question on above proof:

1. What does author mean by "that each edge from "v" to some vertex in S reduces outflow  (from V) by the same amount as it reduces inflow (to S)" ?
   can any one explain with simple example.
2. What does author mean by "each edge to v from some vertex in S reduces inflow (to v) by the same amount as it reduces outflow (from S);
   and all other edges provide inflow or outflow for S1 if and only if they do so for S or v" ? please explain with simple example.
3. What does author mean by " inflow and outflow are equal for S1, and the value of the flow
   is equal to the sum of the values of the flows of v and S minus sum of the flows on the edges connectin v to a vertex in S (either direction)." ? pls explain with example .

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at the [min cut max flow theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem): it'll wrap it all up for you, I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paragraph is not very well written but if I get it right in short the author means that flow from v to a vertex from S(name this vertex t) increases the outflow from v with a given value, but it also increases the inflow of t with the same value. So adding such an edge we still have that the summar inflow equals the summar outflow. Similarly for an edge from a vertex from S to v we increse the inflow of v and the outflow of the vertex in S with the same value. All othere edges connect two vertices from S and by the inductive assumption their summar inflow equals their summar outflow. Please note that instead of the term reduces the outflow for vertex v I used "increases the outflow" as it seems to be more natural for me. 
I would not dare to guess what does the author mean by the last sentence of the second to last paragraph.

Hope that helps at least a little bit.

I believe there are books where this particular theorem seems to be better explained for instance "Introduction to algorithms" written by Thomas H. Cormen,Charles E. Leiserson,Ronald L. Rivest,Clifford Stein.